# URL endpoint to retrieve a document in a list based on a key value

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to setup a document list to be maintained in SharePoint Online, where each document is associated with one or more integer and/or string keys (in that list or as a separate SP List), and provide users with a URL endpoint such as "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/mysite/mydocumentlistendpoint?key=NNN" which would retrieve the document having that (hopefully unique!) key. Setting up the lists is fairly trivial: but what are my options for providing the retrieval endpoint?

Do I need to code and deploy a SharePoint or Azure app (of what sort?) to redirect a GET request to a specific document URL, or is there a way of providing a URL interpreted by SharePoint out of the box that could do the retrieval in one step with no (extra) code? Should I create error pages for each of the document types, trying to get a URL shortener approved in the company, trying to get a script editor web part approved for our SharePoint Online, or are there simpler options? Managed paths do not seem to go to the document level, and require high management privileges.

My use case is a model repository tool (with models of processes, information, systems, capabilities &c), presenting graphical models in its own web interface to a wide swathe of users in my enterprise, where I want to provide a URL in the header of the HTML representation of the model, pointing to a document explaining how to interpret and interact with this specific type of model content. So, for instance, in an information model, the model header URL could look like "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/mysite/mydocumentlistendpoint?key=42", where 42 by a lucky chance happens to be the integer type of the model in the repository tool.

Comment: Have you considered the out-of-the-box document ID feature? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984

Comment: Yeah, that's a possible partial solution, though the mapping from type identifier to document ID would still need to be done somewhere. Even if the SP identifiers can be replaced by my type ID's, I think it still would require multiple copies of those documents that need to be shared between several type ID's.

Comment: So you're saying an ID wouldn't be unique to one document? That doesn't sound like a unique ID?

Comment: No, the identity is on the other side: several model types may map to one document. I'd like to keep  the management of that mapping in synch with the document list, preferably by attaching multiple ID's to the documents, or through a secondary list.

Comment: Sounds like you're best off using the managed metadata service and maybe using search filters to surface documents that you need